# Is there any way to use external function in IQueryable or simplify the string operations?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have this query which returns `IQueryable`.

```
return _staffQueryService.ClearAllFilters().OnlyActiveStaff().ExcludeContractors()
    .Get().Select(s => new AutoCompleteItem
    {
        Value = s.PersonnelNumber,
        Text = s.FullName +
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) ? string.Empty : " (") +
               ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) +
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) ? string.Empty : ")") +
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : " (") +
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : ("x" + (s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber))) +
               (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : ")"),
        Email = s.Email
    });
```

As you can see I had to use a ton of ugly looking string operations to prepare the output.
I had to repeat all the strings checks multiple times.

This could have been done in a very prettier way if I could use external function, which I cannot because it is in `IQueryable` context.

I have a limitation that I cannot cast it to `IEnumerable`, I have to return the result in `IQueryable` form only.

Considering these limitations, is there something that can be done to this ugly looking code, to simplify it?

Comment: Because it must still be an `IQueryable` everything has to be done *on the server side*. So all you could do would be to create a user-defined function on the server and call this within your `IQueryable`. AFAIK you can also manage (create, update, delete) UDFs within an EF core migration, but the code itself has to be written in SQL and not in C#.

Comment: @Oliver - That is actually a good idea. But the problem is that I still have to maintain this piece of code in C#, so do you know if I can use UDF within this linq query?

Comment: FYI - You could reduce those last 3 lines to a single line, something like `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : " (x" + (s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) + ")")`,

Comment: It is possible to run C# code on the server side: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15. It should also be possible to add the corresponding code manually to a migration to register (or unregister) such an assembly, but I never did this.

Comment: Pretty interesting, as far as I understand since you are dealing with the IQueryable interface everytime you have written in your select is translated to sql. It would be interesting to see how this gets translated. My guess it that this would be alot more unreadable than the code you have right now. But I could be wrong. The only thing that would make sense to me is that this whole string concatination and move it to a computed column in sql. @YD9 answer suggested a func variable but this only works on IQueryable if you wrap it in an Expression eg. Expression<Func<T, V>>

Comment: computed column or function stored procedure, update trigger whatever :D

Answer (score -2):

You can extract the mapping to a `func` delegate as and use it as a selector.

```
Func<MyModel, AutoCompleteItem> selector = s => new AutoCompleteItem
        {
            Value = s.PersonnelNumber,
            Text = s.FullName +
                   (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) ? string.Empty : " (") +
                   ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) +
                   (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.SectionCode) ? null : s.SectionCode) ?? (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DivisionCode) ? null : s.DivisionCode)) ? string.Empty : ")") +
                   (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : " (") +
                   (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : ("x" + (s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber))) +
                   (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.FirstPhoneNumber ?? s.SecondPhoneNumber) ? string.Empty : ")"),
            Email = s.Email
        };
```

You can use it like this:

```
_staffQueryService.ClearAllFilters().OnlyActiveStaff().ExcludeContractors()
    .Get().Select(selector).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: That wouldn't help, cause in that case you would call the query against the database at this point and do anything else locally instead on the server side. Just applying `.AsQueryable()` doesn't solve anything, it just hides the problems.